# onPause/Resume/Start/Stop order

Tags: java, android

Im trying to detect the global Application onPause. For doing it I'm registering every Activity onResume, onPause, onStop calls. 
I'd like to know if I can assume the calling order (when the ActivityA leaves and enters the ActivityB) is always:

```
A ->onPause;
B ->onStart;
B ->onResume;
A ->onStop;
```

Is there some case where the A-> onStop is called before the B-> onResume?

I'm asking that because thats the method I'm using for detecting the globalPause and want to validate it:

```
 onPause(){
     active=false;
 }

 onResume(){
     active=true;
 }

 onStop(){
    if(!active) onGlobalPause();
 }
```

thanks

Comment: Try putting some time-consuming code into `Activity` B's `onCreate` and `onStart` as an experiment. Perhaps even `Thread.sleep(3000)` in each - not advised for production code but worth trying for test purposes.